# new clutch set- vibration at bitting point

Tags: vw, clutch

Replaced dual mass flywheel and clutch with release bearing last weekend on my vw tdi. There is vibration through the car at bitting point, in 1st gear the most, can feel in reverse as well, but not as bad. All other shifting is smooth, clutch isn't slipping. Car's engine mounts only 6 months old. Is it normal?

Comment: I don't have experience with new clutches, but perhaps your clutch and flywheel are still undergoing break-in?

Comment: i really hope so...

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Comments in comments and answers in answers!

Comment: yes. you are correct it is stock level. well i shall see after few hundred miles then. Thank you

Comment: @Kitsunemimi - Good point ... added :o)

Comment: Are you sure you didn't get a big fat greasy thumbprint on any of the friction surfaces?

Comment: No. Its actually getting better. Only done 20 miles in city driving.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on how bad it is as to whether it's normal. I've experienced it both ways with new clutches, but it usually has to do with what performance level the clutch is made to. Since it's a dual mass, I'd assume it's stock performance levels. Normal break-in period for a new clutch is 500 miles of city driving (highway driving doesn't count). You should definitely see a difference by then if there's going to be one.